# Durandal Passing parameter to custom dialog

Tags: modal-dialog, durandal

I am trying to implement a custom dialog like the one describe [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21830679/807223) or [HERE](http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#so/21821997)

In the js file I fdefined the modal's view as

```
var CustomDialog = require('./customModal')
```

var DialogModel = require('./MyModel')
However, my DialogModel requires as parameter in its activate method. The route for the MyModel is defined to take a parameter and its activate method is defined as

```
function activate(routedata){
....
}
```

To open the dialog, I have

```
 var routedata = 90;
 this.dialog = new CustomDialog('My title', new DialogModel());
 this.dialog.show()
```

How do I pass this route data to the path?

Comment: i don't understand the question and it's not clear enough to correct mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass activation data in `show`:

```
 var routedata = 90;
 this.dialog = new CustomDialog('My title', new DialogModel());
 this.dialog.show(routedata);
```

And proxy it in your CustomDialog:

```
define(['plugins/dialog'], function (dialog) {
    var CustomModal = function (title, model) {
        this.title = title;
        this.model = model;
    };

    CustomModal.prototype.ok = function() {
         dialog.close(this, this.model);
     };

    CustomModal.prototype.show = function(activationData){
       return dialog.show(this, activationData);
    };

    return CustomModal;
});
```

Comment: Seems to worl well with the show return being return dialog.show('viewmodels/MyModel, activationData). I can get the parameter passed in the activiate method. However,, when I  use return dialog.show(this, activationData), the parameter is undefined.